# How can I perform Node Analysis with dependent source?

Tags: thevenin, nodal-analysis, norton

I have the following circuit as shown in the picture. My question is how can I perform Node analysis in this circuit in the node \$V_{0}\$?

I want to find \$i_{1}\$ but without KCL or KVL. Just the node analysis in the node \$V_{0}\$.

I tried :
\$\frac{V_{0}}{6} +\frac{V_{0}}{4}-1 = 0  \$ ignoring the ccvs. If I take it into account the dependent ccvs how the node analysis will be?

Any help?

(Side note: I know that KCL in node \$V_{0}\$ and KVL in the left sub circuit solves it but I want to see the node analysis how will be changed if I take into account the dependent source. The current source 1A is the circuit excitation in the terminal A,B)

[image]

Comment: Well, if you ground the bottom node then Vo/6 is i1. So the dependent source is Vo/3. Does that make sense, so far?

Comment: @periblepsis yes you are using Ohm's Law.Can you continue your thought?

Comment: So the voltage over the 4 Ohm resistor must be Vo minus the dependent source, which is Vo/3. So that means Vo - Vo/3. But that is just 2/3*Vo.

Comment: So the current sinking into the 4 Ohm must be [(2/3)*Vo]/4 or 1/6 Vo. And the current sinking into the 6 Ohm must be Vo/6 or i1, as already mentioned. The sum of these two is Vo/3, not so? And these two sinking currents must be equal to 1 A. If Vo/3 = 1, then what is Vo?

Comment: @periblepsis what is the node analysis equation for this circuit ?

Comment: Just put it all together. You've got all the pieces now. The full expression would be written: Vo/6 {the current in the 6 Ohm} + (Vo - 2*i1)/4 {the current in the 4 Ohm} = 1 A {the current sourced into the node}. Then substitute i1=Vo/6 to get: Vo/6 + (Vo - 2*Vo/6)/4 = 1 A.

Comment: You could just as well swap positions of the dependent source and the 4 Ohm resistor, since they are both in series with each other. The equation would be written out a little bit differently. But the result would be the same. See if you can do it that way.

Comment: Here's [your picture back at you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7Wf6.png).

Comment: The dependent source does not change anything in the nodal equations.  You proceed exactly the same as with regular independent sources. The only differences is that instead of the ordinary value (2V or 1A) you have (2 * I1) or similar. And I1 is also expressed in terms of nodal voltages (Vo/6) in this case.

Comment: @periblepsis one more time I do not know how to thank you.You are extremely helpful with very detail answers like that.I am getting V_{0} =  3 as final result as it should be.

Comment: @G36 So if instead of 2i_{1} let's say that I had 2V independent source the node equation would be :  Vo/6 + (Vo - 2V)/4 = 1 A.No matter if the resistor of 4 ohm is after the source or before the source ?

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson Yes, indeed the node equation would be : Vo/6 + (Vo - 2V)/4 = 1 A.

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson Have a look at [these equivalent schematics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GaqBe.png). The KCL statement remains the same in all of them, of course. But you can move things around. Looking at the lower right schematic -- the simpler one -- you can see that I2=(Vo-V1)/R1. Now, if you change V1 from 2*I1 and instead make it 2 V, all that happens is that you modify V1. But the general equation for I2 is still the same. Just one of the terms in it goes from 2*I1 to 2 V, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want to find i1 but without KCL or KVL.*

I'd convert the dependent voltage source into a dependent current source like this: -

[image]

Then, it's clear that the current through the 4 Ω resistor is \$1 - 0.5i_1\$.

I'd multiply \$i_1\$ by 6 to get \$V_{O}\$ and, equate this to \$1 - 0.5i_1\$ multiplied by 4 (also equals \$V_O\$): -

\$6\cdot i_1 = 4(1 - 0.5i_1)\$

Do a few lines of rearranging to find that \$i_1\$ equals 0.5 amps.

Sanity check in microcap: -

[image]

**Note that I haven't used KVL or KCL**.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to apply KVL or KCL, if the network is in the right configuration (as in this case) then apply Millman's theorem:

[image: Circuit]